# Change title of Document Library programatically with JSOM

Tags: sharepoint-addin

I am trying to change the title of one of the document libraries programatically with JSOM.

This is the code but it is not working... any ideas?

```
function UpdateDocumentLibraryName(oNewWebsite) {

var oList = oNewWebsite.get_lists().getByTitle('Documentos');

oList.set_title = 'Contenidos Pedagogia';
oList.update();
context.load(oList);
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You are missing [SP.ClientContext.executeQueryAsync method](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/dn168907%28v=office.15%29.aspx) that performs the changes.

How to update List title via JSOM:

```
var oldListTitle = 'Documents';
var newListTitle = 'Public Documents';

var context = SP.ClientContext.get_current();
var list = context.get_web().get_lists().getByTitle(oldListTitle);   
list.set_title(newListTitle);
list.update();
context.executeQueryAsync(
function(){
  console.log('List Title has been updated');    
}, 
function(sender,args){
  console.log(args.get_message());    
});
```

Comment: `context.load(list);` should be called before `context.executeQueryAsync`?

Answer (score 1):

try this code

```
function UpdateDocumentLibraryName(oNewWebsite) {

var oList = oNewWebsite.get_lists().getByTitle('Documentos');

oList.set_title('Contenidos Pedagogia');
oList.update();
context.load(oList);
}
```

If above not worked then check this post:
http://sharepointreffer.blogspot.com/2013/08/updateedit-list-title-using-javascript.html